# How do I use a php array within an array returned to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I've been at this for more than half a day trying to figure out this problem and I swear I've tried every possible thing. So here's the idea behind what I'm trying to do... Every 10 seconds Javascript performs an AJAX call to see if you have any friends online, then returns a list of users, their status etc... Instead of formatting everything from PHP, I'll be formatting it from Javascript for various reasons... So here's what happens:

**Javascript**
// Let's get the data from the controller

```
 $.post('/pagething', { datastuff }, function(data){
 if(data.status == 'ok'){

 // Magic nonsense here that can translate the array example:
 var keys = Object.keys(data.allfriends);

   }
 } etc...
```

**PHP**
// Let's skip other code in the controller and focus on the important stuff

```
 $friends_information = array(
 'userid' => array();
 'username' => array();
 'avatar' => array();
 'status' => array();
 );

 foreach($result_from_my_friends_model as $row){
 // For ease of read, i'll just associate things with $row

 $friends_information["userid"][] = $row->user_id;
 $friends_information["username"][] = $row->username;
 $friends_information["avatar"][] = $row->avatar;
 $friends_information["status"][] = $row->status;
 }

 $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'allfriends' => $friends_information);
 return json_encode($result);
 exit();
```

The closest I've gotten is to either get the results by say username, or userid for example through a new object or getting the entire result but unable to distinguish between keys since object[0][1] for instance would return undefined.

Thank you in advanced, this stuff is tough to understand :/

Comment: It would be easier if you didn't make a separate array for each column, but instead did it as `$friends_informationp[] = $row;`

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware that you could just do that. I'm giving it a go right now and we'll see how it goes. :)

Comment: You don't even need to do that, since the original `$result_from_my_friends_model` is already an array organized like that. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to put each column into a separate element of `$friend_array`, things are generally easier if you keep all the data related to a particular friend together in an object. So do:

```
$result = array('status' => 'ok', 'allfriends' => $result_from_my_friends_model);
echo json_encode($result);
```

In the Javascript, make sure you specify that the result is JSON:

```
$.post('/pagething', { datastuff }, function(data) {
    if (data.status == 'ok') {
        $.each(data.allfriends, function(i, friend) {
            // do stuff with friend.userid, friend.username, friend.avator, friend.status
        });
    }
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Brilliant! I presume that i, friend declares a new object instance in the name of friend? It works great, and I switched it to a simpler array so I use friend[0] for example. I'll look up .each for more info. Much thanks!

Comment: `i, friend` are the parameters to the callback. `i` and `friend` are the index and element of the array elements as it loops through the array. Read the documentation of `$.each`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

You already have your list_of_friend in your `keys`variable of js. Just iterate through it then you will get your desired result. Best of luck